# Download file with members of WhatsApp group

Tags: whatsapp

I participate in a WhatsApp group and would like to know if it is possible to download a TXT list from all members of this group.

Answer (score 1):

It's not something that exists builtin, maybe there's an extension or a user script that will do that.

The maximum you can download is your chat history from a group, which will contain the names of the participants that sent messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

But you can make use of Google Sheet.

- Firstly open web WhatsApp
- Secondly Enable Inspect Element
- Thirdly Point over to Group Icon you can see the phone numbers
- Finally Copy the number shown in inspect element, paste them to your
  Google sheet and then you can format it accordingly